# How to remove green extra space in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

[image]

how to remove bottom extra green area in swiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                    Text("test")
                }
                .background(Color.green)
//                .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```